# Upper bound for coefficients of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am doing the following problem.

Suppose $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is an analytic function on the unit disc $|z|<1$. Let $0<r<1$. Prove that
$$|a_n|r^n\leq \max\{4A(r),0\}-2Ref(0),$$
where $A(r)=\max_{|z|=r}Ref(z)$.

Here is my approach (but fail). Let $u(z)=Ref(z)$, then I have computed that (hope my computation is correct)
$$Re(a_n)=\frac{1}{\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}u(r,\theta)\cos(n\theta)d\theta.$$
$$Im(a_n)=\frac{1}{\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}u(r,\theta)\sin(n\theta)d\theta.$$
Then, I used these to get the estimate
\begin{align*}
|a_n|r^n\leq&r^n(|Re(a_n)|+|Im(a_n)|)
\\\leq&\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|u|
\\=&\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg(\int_{u\geq 0}u-\int_{u\leq 0}u\bigg)
\\=&\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg(2\int_{u\geq 0}u-\int_0^{2\pi}u\bigg)
\\\leq&\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg(4\pi A(r)-\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u\bigg)
\\=&8A(r)-4u(0),
\end{align*}
where I have used the mean value formula
$$u(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(r,\theta)d\theta$$
for harmonic function.
But it is seems that which is still over estimated (a factor of 2). Is the question wrong or there is a better way to obtain the required estimate? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For any estimate containing the max of the real part try to examine $g(z)=\exp(f(z))$, since then $|g(z)|=\exp(Re(f(z)))$.

Answer (score 1):

One of the oldest   tricks in the complex variables book is the identity
$$|a|=\max_{\theta\in \mathbb R} \operatorname{Re}(e^{i\theta}a) \tag{1}$$
which holds for every complex number $a$. Thus, one can obtain an estimate of absolute value  by estimating the real part of something, which has the advantage of being *linear*.

If the above hint is not enough, read further.

> Fix $n$. Choose $\theta$ so that the $n$th coefficient of   $g(z)=f(e^{i\theta}z)$ is real (you can even make it positive). The function $g$ satisfies the same assumptions as $f$. Applied to $g$, your inequalities produce the desired estimate, since there is no imaginary part of the coefficient.